# Cannot select a button based on its class

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want my `jQuery` datepicker (jQuery UI 1.8.13) to generate a report only when I click the 'Done' button.

[image]

The `onClose` event is not good because that is triggered also when I click somewhere else (not in the datepicker) and I need to generate the report only when the 'Done' button is pressed. Therefore I need to add an `onclick` callback to the 'Done' button. However I can not find a `jQuery` selector that will match the 'Done' button. I have tried the `$('.ui-corner-all')` but that will also find other elements too. 
So, I have tried `$('.ui-priority-primary')` (because AFAIK this is the only element that has this style), but it does not match the button ...

1. I need a selector that will only match that 'Done' button.
2. Why is `$('.ui-priority-primary')` not working?

Please find the sample code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7ThB8/26/).

**UPDATE** I use a this datepicker as a monthpicker, so I do not have dates to click on. Therefore it is important that I need to put the callback on the 'Done' button as I have stated above.

Comment: I'm using Chrome and it doesn't work for me as is. If you click on anything it gives the alert.

Comment: Have you tried the solution I provided? It is the best way to make this work.

Comment: @mrtsherman: Yes, I have tried it and it works. Thanks for the solution and the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as it not working, this is because the control is created after your binding takes place. If you use delegate then it will work. Although I think Darin's answer is probably a better solution, I am providing this as it directly answers the 'why' of your question.

http://jsfiddle.net/7ThB8/30/

```
$('body').delegate('.ui-priority-primary', 'click', function() {
    alert('done was clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

How about using the [`onSelect`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onSelect) event which is triggered when a date is selected:

```
$('.date').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: The onSelect is not a good solution in my case because I need the  action to be triggered when I click on the 'Done' button. Actually I use monthpicker which does not have the dates displayed.